# Magento 2.3: Not able to insert data using custom Patch

Tags: magento2.3.2

I have upgraded my Magento version from **2.2.7** to **2.3.2**. I am working on a module where I have to create a table and insert some sample data.

As per the new conventions introduced in Magento 2.3.x, I created the table using **app/code/[Packagename]/[Modulename]/etc/db_schema.xml**. The table has been created successfully.

Now, I am trying to add data to the table using the patch file **app/code/[Packagename]/[Modulename]/Setup/Patch/Data/InsertTemplates.php**

The apply() function code is as follows:

```
public function apply()
{
    $data = array();
    $data[0]['template_name'] = __('Default Template 1');
    $data[0]['style_color'] = '#DC8C71';
    $data[0]['text_color'] = '#949392';
    $data[0]['caption'] = __('Gift Card');

    $data[1]['template_name'] = __('Default Template 2');
    $data[1]['style_color'] = '#DC8C71';
    $data[1]['text_color'] = '#636363';
    $data[1]['caption'] = __('Gift Card');
}
```

When I run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=[Packagename]_[Modulename]

php bin/magento s:up
```

Both commands are running successfully, but the data is not being inserted into the table.

Can anyone help me understand, what can be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check whether you are using the correct **Packagename** and **Modulename** when running the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=[Packagename]_[Modulename]
```

Next, Magento uses the table **patch_list** to keep the patch version's history to prevent a re-run of the patch code.

Please check whether there is already an entry of your patch in the **patch_list** table.

I hope it give some clue.

Bonus: The command

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=[Packagename]_[Modulename]
```

is not required when you install new data using a patch.

This command is only required when there is any database schema changed.